# Спарсить меню телеграм бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

подскажите пожалуйста есть ли способ спарсить, скопировать у телеграм бота меню которое представлено в виде клавиатуры и Inline keyboards (на картинке к примеру Yes, they certainly are)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спарсить текст из чата? это не инлайн кнопки

Comment: скопировать у телеграм бота меню которое представлено в виде клавиатуры

Answer (score 2):

```
def key(message):
    button_1 = types.KeyboardButton('Yes, they certainly are')
    button_2 = types.KeyboardButton("i'm not quite sure")
    button_3 = types.KeyboardButton('No.')
    kb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
    kb.add(button_1)
    kb.add(button_2)
    kb.add(button_3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Message', reply_markup=kb)
```